# Clarifications on parameters in models and distribution

Tags: regression, distributions, estimation

I'm looking for help clarifying the concept of parameters in statistics. Mainly, I'm having trouble understanding the commonality or difference between **distribution parameter** and **model parameter**.

When describing **distributions**, (e.g., normal distribution, binomial distribution, etc) we use the word 'parameters' for normal - mean and standard deviation, and binomial - trial number and probability.

And simultaneously, when we talk about the **model**, we also use the word, "parameters" For linear regression, slope and intercept are the ones. And these days, more frequently, model parameters of the neural net would be the other example.

**The reason why I'm feeling confused is the targets that each parameter describes seem to be different in these two cases**. The former want seems to be more focused on describing "distribution" and the latter one on "model". For example,  we consider this in the neural net classifier, the input data can have their own distribution (e.g., normal distribution parameterized by their sample mean and standard deviation) while the model can have their own parameter which forms themselves (e.g., weights that form each layer and bias matrix)

Are they essentially identical or just share the same terminology?

Comment: Viewing regression as a model for the conditional distributions, some parameters of these distributions specifically determine how they are affected by x (eg, $\beta$'s.)  But all parameters ultimately refer to these distributions, so there is no confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reconcile the notions of *model* and of *distribution* is to see they are both ultimately used to compute the probability of an observation.

For instance, let's assume that an observation $y$ was generated from a normal distribution with parameters $\theta = [\mu,\sigma]$. Hence, the probability of the observation given the parameters $p(y|\theta)$ is the density function of the normal distribution:

$$
p(y|\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} exp(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})
$$

Now, let us assume a linear regression model with slope and origin $\theta = [a,b]$. Similarly, it is possible to compute the probability of an observation $(x,y)$ (where $x$ is the independent and $y$ is the dependent) given the parameter $\theta$, i.e. $p(y|x,\theta)$. If you disregard noise in your model, then $p(y|x,\theta) = 1$ if $y = ax+b$, and $0$ otherwise. If you assume a level of noise $\sigma$ in your linear model, then $p(y|x,\theta)$ is the density of a normal distribution with mean $ax+b$ and std $\sigma$.

In both cases, the goal is the same: to compute $p(y|\theta)$. A *distribution* usually refers to [classical canonical distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions), while a *model* usually has an ad-hoc probability function (e.g. can be a function of several distributions).